# Equivalence of Baire Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, baire-category

In my studies of functional analysis I have come across this two statements of the Baire Category Theorem.

> 1. Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Let $U_n$ be a dense, open set for each $n \in \Bbb N$. Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ is dense.

And

> 2. Let $(X.d)$ be a complete metric space. $A_0, A_1,..$ are closed subsets. If  $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n $ contains an open ball, then at least one of the $A_n$ contains an open ball.

Now I am struggling with how to show $1.\Rightarrow 2.$  ,
unfortunately our professor didn't proved this one and we can't use the assertion:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Let $U_n$ be a closed subset, without interior point for each $n \in \Bbb N$. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ has no interior point.

Which is equivalent to $1.$ and $2.$
Maybe it's a silly question or it's obvious to see, but thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? Where exactly did you fail while trying to prove 1. $\Rightarrow$ 2.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ contains an open ball, then its interior is not empty. On the other hand,$$\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)^\complement=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^\complement,$$which is in intersection of a sequence of open sets. If no $A_n$ contains an open ball, then every $A_n$ has empty interior and therefore every $A_n^\complement$ is dense. But then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^\complement$ is dense, which is impossible, since $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ contains an open ball.